# Can't see specific order magento on admin after supee-7405

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, sales-order, ce-1.8.1.0, supee-7405

After a couple of days that the patch `supee-7405` was released I've decided to install the it.

I did a backup of my website because I could see there were a lot of files to modify and I suspected that something could be wrong and yes, something has been wrong.

When I am on the admin panel and I go to `sales`>`orders` it looks like everything is ok. But when I try to access to any of those orders I can't see the information of that order.
[image]

Does this have a solution or I should go back to my backup?

Comment: Interesting, you should be getting an error in your webserver logs and/or in your magento logs, could you post it here please ?

Comment: Where can I find this? I know I can get error information when Magento gives error and you can't even access to the website on `var/report`. But where can I see such non-critical error information?

Comment: Depends on your server, `var/log` for Magento logs. To get your server error logs, you can do it via cPanel or an other server admin web access. If you have full access to your server via SSH you can find them in the `/var/log` folder

Comment: Ok, I found it: `var/log/system.log`. The problem is the file weights 20GB and it would take a lot of time to download it.

Comment: Wow, I suggest you delete it and reaccess the order page. It will update the file with only the error you're interested in

Comment: I've just done it and this file is growing so fast. I've accessed it and I can see nothing related to sales or order

Comment: Look for exceptions.log as well in the same directory it may be an exception triggered. Also, Try viewing the source, sometimes with errors like that it will output straight into the page but the general markup makes it invisible to the rendered view.

Comment: I've just fixed it! It seems there was an error on the files which is solved with patch `supee-7405 version-1.1`. Thank you very much for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is just installing the 1.1 version which can be found [here](https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-install-supee-7405-with-or-without-ssh/#SUPEE7405). I'm not sure if this happens to everyone or only when you install the patch by overwriting patch files through ftp that is how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

You should to go to app/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php then look for some code like this $links = []; and change to $links = array(); for me it is at line 124. Or you can search inside Sales.php file using ctrl+f command , and try to search for [] then change to array(). Hope it helps you. Thanks!!